# Applying 2nd Newtonian Law for variable mass dynamics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, momentum, mass

I have encountered the following difficulty while solving problems in the variable mass dynamics. One of them said that we have a buggy with sand, of mass $m_0$ initially, with a rate of mass loss $\mu$. The buggy is pulled with a constant force $\vec{F}$.

Of course we may say that:
$$\frac{dm}{dt} = -\mu$$

My approach was to apply Newton's law like this:
$$\frac{d\vec{p}}{dt}=\vec{F} \to (m_0 -\mu t) \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt} - \mu \vec{v} = \vec{F}$$

However, the solution of the problem said that we may write Newton's Law like this:
$$m\vec{a} = \vec{F} \to (m_0 - \mu t) \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt} =\vec{F}$$

Which of them is the correct and why?

Comment: Duplicate. The term $- \mu \vec{v}$ should not be in your equation.  I think that possibly you have assumed that you can use $p = mv \Rightarrow \dot p = m\dot v + \dot m v$ which is certainly not the case. A search of [variable mass](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=variable+mass) on this site will produce a number of posts answering your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable Mass Intuition](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/494534/)